# Adding dynamic rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

iam using jquery to dynamically add multiples rows in my view
here is the code

```
 // start a counter for new row IDs
// by setting it to the number
// of existing rows
$(".datepick").datepicker();
var newRowNum = 0;

// bind a click event to the "Add" link
$('#addnew').click(function() {

    $(".datepick").datepicker("destroy");

    // increment the counter
    newRowNum = $(productTable).children('tbody').children('tr').length + 1;

    // get the entire "Add" row --
    // "this" refers to the clicked element
    // and "parent" moves the selection up
    // to the parent node in the DOM
    var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();

    // copy the entire row from the DOM
    // with "clone"
    var newRow = addRow.clone();

    // set the values of the inputs
    // in the "Add" row to empty strings
    $('input', addRow).val('');

    // insert a remove link in the last cell
    $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">rem<i class="icon-minus"><\/i><\/a>');


    // insert the new row into the table
    // "before" the Add row
    addRow.before(newRow);


    $(".datepick").datepicker();

    // add the remove function to the new row
    $('a.remove', newRow).click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });

    $('#date', newRow).each(function(i) {
        var newID = 'date_' + newRowNum;
        $(this).attr('id', newID);

    });

    // prevent the default click
    return false;
});

// remove's default rows
$('.removeDefault').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Iam using this code with reference to http://jsfiddle.net/vdFaH/200/

In jsfiddle it is working fine, but while coming to my view, it is not working. am i missing any script files.

Comment: That fiddle link is broken. Have you installed jQuery UI?

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Are you remembering to wrap your code in a document ready handler or include it at the end of the document after the elements have loaded? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: I have added document.ready(), even though it is not working. I think $(this).parent().parent() is returning null,thats why am not getting result

Answer (score 0):

I still think you may be missing jQuery UI script files. Take a look at the Datepicker example.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I suppose that depends on his placement of the script. Good point though.

Comment: Maybe somewhen we will know what OP's issue is about, but I just suggest to add idea about `$(documen).ready` to answer for its some kind of completeness.

Comment: I added $(document).ready(),even though it is not getting result

Comment: So you've tried including the jquery UI scripts? Here's how it's done in the Datepicker example: <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>